# How to print "Hello world" in .exe with only built-in windows tools

Tags: windows, assembly, binary, compiler-construction, machine-code

I'm trying to make a simple compiler, and I want to take an input like `print ("Hello world!")` and turn it into something a computer can read, in C++. I don't want to use any intermediate compilers like NASM, but I instead want a method of turning this directly into an exe without any tools that do not come with Windows. So I really have two questions: how do I take instructions from my lexer and turn it into machine code, and then how do I run it?

Any help is greatly appreciated. (My processor is an i7-9750h and I am running windows 11)

Comment: .Net Framework is the part of modern Windows 10/11. `csc.exe` is MS Visual C# compiler for Framework (placed in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\..`). You can use it to compile any code for hello-word output.

Comment: Depending on what operations you need to support, you might try having your lexer output a batch file (or .cmd file).  Thus `print("Hello world!")` would become `echo Hello world!`.  The command language on Windows is very limited when compared to linux, but if your needs are simple, it might suffice.

Comment: "I instead want a method of turning this directly into an exe without any tools that do not come with Windows" That's called writing a compiler.

Comment: @Luke I know, but every tutorial I've seen on this topic uses external tools, that's why I wanted to make it clear

Comment: Why don't you want to use external tools? Why using a decent text editor or IDE instead of notepad would be bad? Why using a compiler would be bad? What are trying to do?

Comment: @MargaretBloom that's not what I mean. Of course I will use things like an IDE, what I mean by external tools is something like an assembly compiler or a tool that converts my instructions to assembly. If this is what is required, I can make a program to turn my instructions into assembly. Then the question becomes how do I turn that assembly into an exe on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses the PE (portable executable) file format for executable EXE files. What is essentially required to run any code natively is to generate a PE file. It is not overly complicated and there are examples on the net.

For a program to print „Hello World“ the PE file needs to include an Import-Table for a few Windows API function from kernel32.dll such as WriteFile. And of course a text section with some code to call it.

I can refer you to a project that I have put on github 2 years ago that does exactly that for a C subset language: https://github.com/urutech/nanocc

What I think is cool is that if your program uses the print function (WriteFile) to generate a PE file than you have the starting point for a bootstrapping compiler that does not rely on any external tools. The first version(s) need to be written either with an existing compiler or you emit hex code to a file. At least that external tool you need: emitting binary hex code to a file. An inspiration could be to look at how somebody bootstrapped a tiny compiler from nothing: https://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/bcompiler